# Visualize a Dirichlet distribution with two parameters using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, bayesian

I'm looking for a way to visualize a Dirichlet distribution Bayesian update with two parameters. Here's how I did it, but I only see one line at first and nothing more. I would be very grateful for help to understand what I am doing wrong.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from scipy.stats import beta, dirichlet
import random
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

a = 0.5
b = 0.5
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
fig =plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax.set_title("Dirichlet Distribution with Bayesian Updating")

for i in range(100):
    if ax.lines:
        for line in ax.lines:
            line.set_xdata(x)
            line.set_ydata(y)
            z = dirichlet.pdf(x=[0.5, 0.5],alpha=[a, b])
            line.set_3d_properties(z)
    else:
        z = dirichlet.pdf(x= [0.5, 0.5],alpha=[a, b])
        ax.plot(x, y, z, 'g')
    x_i = random.choice([0,1])
    a += x_i
    b += (1 - x_i)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(1)
```